# ElGamal signature not verified

Tags: c#, encryption, elgamal

I want to implement an ElGamal encryption from this link https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Portable.Licensing.Security.Cryptography.ElGamal/ElGamalKeyStruct/-/php-elgamalkeystruct-class-examples.html

This is what I have tried so far and have no luck

```
string lic = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
byte[] licenseKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lic);

ElGamalKeyStruct key = new ElGamalKeyStruct();
key.P = new BigInteger(123567890);
key.G = new BigInteger(1234567890);
key.Y = new BigInteger(1234567890);
key.X = new BigInteger(0); //zero

byte[] signature = CreateSignature(licenseKey, key);
bool verified = VerifySignature(licenseKey, signature, key);
```

The `VerifySignature` always returns `false`.

Comment: Don't know El Gamal... But are you sure that any P, G, Y, X are ok?

Comment: From [here](https://www.debjitbiswas.com/elgamal/) it seems P must be prime. 123567890 isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P must be prime. See [here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Programming+.net+security/Part+III+.NET+Cryptography/Chapter+15.+Asymmetric+Encryption/15.3+Extending+the+.NET+Framework/) (that is the ebook from which the code you use was taken):

> Create a random prime number, p. This number is the ElGamal "modulus." The number of bits required to represent p is the size of the public key, so that if p is represented using 1024 bits, then the key created by following the protocol is a 1024-bit key. We will select 607 as our example value.

If you look in the text then there is code to generate El Gamal keys (the `CreateKeyPair()` method)

Comment: I know that. The number 123456789 is just an example, I have ones that generated from `BigInteger`. I cannot create P, G, Y randomly because it's the main value of my license key

Comment: @derodevil: Your example is not very meaningful because you picked values that don't meet the specifications of El Gamal.

Comment: @derodevil If you look at the [example](https://github.com/sven-s/Portable.Licensing) on the github of `Portable.Licensing` you'll see that they generate a completely random key (`Portable.Licensing.Security.Cryptography.KeyGenerator.Create()`) and only then they use it to sign the license (`CreateAndSignWithPrivateKey`)